# What is the best way to gather a lot of data on multiple fields and obtain an average $ per company?

Tags: sql, reporting-services, average

I have a report I am needing to write in sql code that is pulling data of settlements for each defendant on each case we have in our system, indicating the dollar amount of those settlements. So instead of the report listing the defendant, the case(s) they settled in and the dollar amount they settled for in each case as they do now, I just want to show the defendant and the average settlement against ALL cases.

Defendant               Average Settlement

What is the best way to accomplish this? I have the report calculating the average of ALL settlements no matter what defendant but I need it to calculate based on each defendant, not all like a line break between each one.  Then I need it to select the top 30 averages from that list.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the average aggregate function and group by.

```
SELECT Top 30 Defendant, avg(Amount) as AvgSettlement, count(*) as RecordsInAvg
FROM tblName (or your current query)
WHERE... 
GROUP BY Defendant
ORDER BY AvgSettlement desc
```

The order in which things are written is not the order they are executed.
First the database gets the data from the FROM
Then it limits it by the where.
Then it groups the data by group by.  Then it executes the select, then the order by finally the top.  It's not intuitive :P

Comment: Thank you! I will try this out.

Comment: Ok awesome I got the averages to come out right. Now would there be a way to show how many records total for each average line item that were used to get that average? For example if defendant 1 had only 1 record that was included in that average but defendant 10 had 30 records that were calculated in that average. Thank you ahead of time!

Comment: just add `count(*)` to the Select of the query as well. it (updated above) should show the number of records which make up that average.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't calculate correctly. For instance I have one defendant that is showing there are 20 records that make up that average when in reality there was only one. So unfortunately I cannot rely on that. But I appreciate the info very much!

Comment: I'd need to see the query.  If we're grouping by defendant and looking at all their settlements, it should work fine as the group by will let you avg the totals and count all of them by the group by.  So seems odd to me that it wouldn't work; unless you're counting a value from a left join that is null...